# Is it better to have riptide or channeling on a trident?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was considering getting a trident for my survival world, but it seems like there's another duo of enchantments that cannot exist on the trident with the other one (basically just like the issue of *sharpness v. bane of arthropods v. smite*, but with tridents).

Would it be better to have **channeling**, a more long-ranged enchantment and also a good way to get mob heads, or **riptide**, a closer-ranged enchantment that's more for mobility? Or, should I take the time to get two tridents with either enchantment? It seems like both has their own benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely up to you.

The only benefit of getting channelling on a trident is to collect mob heads by making charged creepers or turning villagers into witches or turning pigs into zombie pigmen. Otherwise, it is not that good because it only works when there is a thunderstorm and lightning doesn't do much damage anyway. One extra thing is that channelling can turn red mooshroom into brown mooshrooms and brown mooshrooms into red mooshrooms.

Riptide would be for moving around fast. The downside is that it can only be used in water or during rain.

Whichever one is more important is to you is what you should choose. Personally, I find it best to have both on separate tridents.

Comment: I'm at the end of my rope waiting for lightning to hit a Mooshroom, definitely considering shelling out the time to get a Channeling trident…

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely better to have Loyalty on trident - and Loyalty is incompatible with Riptide.

Both Channeling and Riptide are of marginal use. Riptide is somewhat useful if your gameplay is heavily focused on "sea and air", its use on land is near zero (and before anyone argues about rain - how often do you see rain?). Channeling is only good on the surface during the storm (and how often does THAT happen?) - and even then doesn't deal all that much damage. Its only actual practical purpose is farming mob heads by producing charged creepers.

Loyalty, on the other hand, provides you with a practical ranged weapon that occupies only one inventory slot (both crossbow and bow require extra slots for arrows), never runs out of ammo and while not competitive to fully enchanted bow in terms of damage, it's still a very useful weapon. And it doesn't conflict with Channeling.

Riptide may be fun, allowing for cool tricks like enderpearl golf, or flying in the rain, and may even be helpful combined with impaling when conquering ocean monuments, but it's so heavily situational that if you have a choice, definitely choose Loyalty+Channeling. You can keep Riptide as a second trident for when opportunities to use it arise, but while Loyalty (with possibly Channeling) will be your "daily bread", Riptide won't.

If, though, for some reason you're completely unable to obtain the Loyalty enchantment,  (must be admin-imposed or self-imposed restrictions, it's perfectly possible in normal gameplay), use Riptide as it's marginally useful. A trident with nothing but Channeling on it useless.

Comment: > *how often do you see rain?* < [according to my calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mean%280.5%2C+1%29+%2F+%28mean%280.5%2C+1%29+%2B+mean%280.5%2C+7.5%29%29), (assuming [these ranges](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Rain#Behavior) are a uniform distribution,) it looks like it's raining _about_ 15% of the time.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude And what percentage of time are you spending under ground mining/caving/building, inside buildings building/crafting/secorating, in the Nether and in the End?